# Expo Go does not show error message and crashes

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to make an app with react-native and decided to use expo. When I open the app in expo go on my phone it gets to the splash screen and gives a red box error very quickly and then crashes. I never have time to read the error to figure out what is wrong. How can I fix this?